# Posting data with FormUrlEncoded OR Json in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created generic method from which we are posting data to web apis. And while making posting I am serializing the data to json. Below is my generic method.

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetData<T>(T parm, string url) where T : class
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();

                var result = client.PostAsync(url, SerializeData<T>(parm));

                result.Wait();

                if (result.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // Do something
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            return default(HttpResponseMessage);
        }

 private StringContent SerializeData<T>(T obj)
        {
            string mediaType = "application/json";

            string content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, formatter);

            return new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, mediaType);
        }
```

This work fine if I pass the class object from the caller method Like

```
var result = service.GetData<MyClass>(myclassobj,url);
```

However, for some urls by passing the class object is not working. So, we have written another method where we posting the data in **FormUrlEncodedContent** format like below and it works fine.

```
var Parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Key1", "some value" }, { "Key2", "another value" } };
var EncodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(Parameters);
var postTask = _client.PostAsync(url, EncodedContent);
```

I have tried to send FormUrlEncoded data to JSON method and by changing the Media Type also. But not able to properly serialized it. The apis/services we are consuming are from third party providers.

So my question is what changes are needed in the method which will work with all formats Like JSON, FormUrlEncodedContent etc.

Also, does it depend on how apis are written to which they will work only with specific formats like JSON, FormUrlEncodedContent etc.

Basically I am trying to keep one generic method which will support all formats.

Any help on this appreciated !

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear, but generally speaking, the same action cannot accept both JSON and `x-www-form-urlencoded`. You'll need separate endpoints.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Ok I got it.